# How can I have this jQuery scrollbar directly at the div containers edge?

Tags: jquery, html, css, scrollbar

I am using this scrollbar plugin https://code.falk-m.de/scrollBar/
and I'm having some trouble trying to figure out a way to have the scrollbar touch the edge of the div container (on the right) instead of there being a gap there. Any help is greatly appreciated❤️

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The scrollbar container needs some minor CSS modification.

Find the class, `.sb-scrollbar-container`, in the `scrollBar.css` file and set `right` to `0`. See the code below,

```css
.sb-scrollbar-container {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 5px;
    top: 5px;
    width: 10px;
}
```

Comment: This worked! I completely overlook the `right` code. Thank you so much for your help!